# attachment with Cocoa Scripting Bridge

Tags: xcode, email

Using Cocoa Scripting Bridge to send email
how can I add not only an attachment
but two or more.
Thanks for your help.

```
MailAttachment *theAttachment;

theAttachment = [[[mail classForScriptingClass:@"attachment"] alloc] initWithProperties:
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                [[NSURL URLWithString:attachmentFilePath] path], @"fileName",
                nil]];
[[emailMessageL.content attachments] addObject: theAttachment];
```

Answer (score 0):

Mail's Apple event dictionary does not support adding more than one attachment in a single event, so there is no single method in Scripting Bridge to do it.  However, you can simply run through your quoted code more than once, presumably with different file paths.